# What can cause :focus-visible style to not be applied when using `Element.focus()` to give focus to an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have made a custom `<select>` component that is being used inside a tablecell when editing a row. I've also made a custom hook that can be used in components to give focus to the given element when the component mounts.

In my application, the element receives focus, but the styling I've defined with the `:focus-visible` is not applied. As can we seen in this gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lst6.jpg

When activating "editmode" on the rows, the element is focused, but the styling is not applied. I then click then next input and shift+tab back to the element and then the styling is applied(bordercolor and thickness).

When I try to replicate the issue in a stackoverflow snippet it magically works the way I want it to.

Why is this? What should I look out for that can affect whether or not the `:focus-visible` styling will be applied?

using this hack solves my issue, but I would like to avoid it:

```
element.contentEditable = true;
element.focus();
element.contentEditable = false;
```

I've done some console logs in both my app and the snippet. Both give the same outputs to `element.contentEditable //inherit` and `element.isContentEditable //false` by default.

I can't see any obvious difference between what I have in my application vs what is happening in the snippet.

So again, what should I look out for that can affect whether or not the `:focus-visible` styling will be applied? What is the difference here?

```js
const useFocusOnMount = (ref) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current.focus();
    }
  }, [ref]);
};


const App = (props) => {
  const divRef = React.useRef(null)
  
  useFocusOnMount(divRef);

  return (
    <table>
      <tr>
        <div ref={divRef} role="listbox" tabindex="0" className="focusable">
          <div data-testid="displayValue">Lol</div>
          </div>
      </tr>
    </table>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.focusable {
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
  background: green;
}

.focusable::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
}

.focusable:focus {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.focusable:focus-visible {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: the :focus-visible pseudo-class will only show when the element receives keyboard focus. the only exception to this rule are <input> elements, they also apply the :focus-visible when clicked or programmatically handed focus.

Comment: Should a `<div>` element get :focus-visible then if you call .focus() on it? Because it does here, but not in my application unless i set `contentEditable=true` right before i call focus() on it.

Comment: strange behavior indeed, I think it probably has something to do with it being launched inside an iFrame here. UAs only sometimes visibly indicate focus (such as by drawing a “focus ring”), instead using a variety of heuristics to visibly indicate the focus only when it would be most helpful to the user. The :focus-visible pseudo-class matches a focused element in these situations only, allowing authors to change the appearance of the focus indicator without changing when a focus indicator appears. [Selectors Level 4 focus-visible](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#the-focus-visible-pseudo)